# Why is my blogdown website not updating despite working locally?

Tags: r, netlify, blogdown

I'm trying to update a [project website](https://www.irishecologicalassociation.org/home/) using hugo via `blogdown` through R and RStudio.

I'm making edits to the Tweet embedded on the [front page](https://www.irishecologicalassociation.org/home/) as well as the people on the [committee page](https://www.irishecologicalassociation.org/committee/).

All of the updates work fine when I run the page locally with `blogdown::serve_site()`. However, the edits aren't being realised online.

The changes seem to be recorded on GitHub so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Here's the associated [GitHub page](https://github.com/irish-ecology/websiteV2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the issue was related to the build image on Netlify.

Netlify gives some background about it here https://answers.netlify.com/t/please-read-end-of-support-for-xenial-build-image-everything-you-need-to-know/68239

As they say on the site, "You can upgrade to the latest build image in the Netlify UI under Site settings > Build & deploy > Continuous Deployment > Build image selection."